# Django forms.ChoiceField() I'm overlooking something

Tags: django, choicefield

Probably I'm making some beginner mistake. I'm trying to get forms.ChoiceField() working. The user should be able to select from a dropdownlist so as to select 1, 2, 3 or four collectors in a row.
When I run the code the user is able to select the choices from the dropdownlist however the number_collectors_per_row variable is not set to the appropriate integer value.

I defined choices.py as follows:

```
COLLECTORS_PER_ROW_CHOICES = (
    (1, 'one collector'),
    (2, 'two collectors'),
    (3, 'three collectors'),
    (4, 'four collectors')
)
```

The System model is defined as follows:

```
from .choices import *

class System(models.Model):
    project     = models.ForeignKey('solgeo.Project', related_name='systems', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    system_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    number_collector_rows = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    number_collectors_per_row = models.IntegerField(choices = COLLECTORS_PER_ROW_CHOICES)
```

The form is defined as follows:

```
from .choices import *

class SystemForm(forms.ModelForm):

    number_collectors_per_row = forms.ChoiceField(required=True, choices = COLLECTORS_PER_ROW_CHOICES)

    class Meta:
        model = System
        fields = [
            'system_name',
            'number_collector_rows'
        ]
```

The SystemUpdateView is defined as follows:

```
class SystemUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    template_name = 'system/detail-update.html'
    form_class = SystemForm

    def get_object(self):
        return System.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk_system'])

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(SystemUpdateView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['title'] = 'Update System'
        return context

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(SystemUpdateView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        return kwargs
```

Hope someone can help me out, thanks in  advance.

Comment: I do not use the kwargs['user'] = self.request.user, so probably I could remove the whole get_form_kwargs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `number_collectors_per_row` to your form's `Meta.fields`.

```
class SystemForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = System
        fields = [
            'system_name',
            'number_collector_rows',
            'number_collectors_per_row',
        ]
```

Note that since you are using the same choices in the form as the model, you don't have to redefine the field in the form.

Comment: Yes thanks that's it. Save me another hour looking over my code. Thanks a lot.